# How to solve this ODE: $\dfrac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}}=c$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\dot{y}$ is the derivative of y with respect to x, i.e. $\dot{y} \equiv 
\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. And here comes the question: How to solve the following ODE?
$$\dfrac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}}=c$$Where c is constant.
I used Mathematica 9.0 to give the answer $y=\pm\dfrac{cx}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}+b(or\,a)$ where a, b are constants. But I want to know how to solve it? Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a cute geometrical way to look at it:

Consider the curve $(x, y(x))$ in the $xy$-plane.  It is the graph of the function $y(x)$.  The tangent vector to this curve is $(1, \dot y(x))$; the magnitude of this vector is $\sqrt{1 + \dot y^2}$.  Then the equation

$\dfrac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}}=c \tag{1}$

says that $\sin \theta(x) = c$, where $\theta(x)$ is the angle the slope of the curve makes with the $x$-axis.  Since $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, we have $\cos \theta(x) = \pm \sqrt{1 - c^2}$.  Thus $\tan \theta(x) = \pm c /\sqrt{1 - c^2}$ is constant; the curve $y(x)$ is thus a line of slope $\pm c /\sqrt{1 - c^2}$.  So $y'(x) = \pm c /\sqrt{1 - c^2}$, from which $y(x) = \pm c x /\sqrt{1 - c^2} + b$ for some constant $b$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: nice answer as always

Comment: @ Semsem:  and once again I thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $\dot{y}$ using the quadratic formula (technically just isolate) to get $\dot{y}=\pm c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$. Take it from there.